# C# Event of Control from List<Control>

Tags: c#, list, events, controls

This is my code:

```
List<TabPage> _tpList = new List<TabPage>();
int _iTabCount = 0;

    TabPage CreateNewTab(string sTitle)
    {
        TabPage t = new TabPage();
        t.BackColor = Color.White;
        t.Text = sTitle;
        _tpList.Add(t);
        this.Tab.Controls.Add(_tpList[_iTabCount]);
        _iTabCount++;
        return _tpList[_iTabCount - 1];
    }
```

I want to handle the Click Event of the one of the Control in List `_tpList`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your event handler just after the creation of the tabPage

```
TabPage t = new TabPage(); 
t.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tabPage1_Click);
.....
this.Tab.Controls.Add(_tpList[_iTabCount]);    
.....
```

and add  code like this:

```
    private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage t = sender as TabPage;
        if(t.Text == "MyPage")
           ......
    }
```

eventually you could use the Tag property or the Name property of the TabPage to set an unique identifier for the page, so you could do a better check on the tabPage1_Click to discover the actual page clicked.

However, I wish to point that the best way to know which tabpage is active on a tab control, is by handling the Selected event on the tab control itself. That event has a TabControlEventArgs  containing the current selected tabpage.

```
    private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.TabPage.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not just use [Control.MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) that `TabPage` get from its parent class.

Comment: just handle MouseClick on TabPage like `t.Click += new System.EventHandler(TabPageClicked);`